# Где CLIPS хранит "факты"?

Tags: linux, memory, clips

Где CLIPS хранит "факты" и как узнать максимальный объём, который может использовать CLIPS под их хранение? Есть ли какие-либо ограничения на этот счёт?

Comment: а что такое "clips"?

Comment: @KoVadim https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLIPS